Refactoring the query
Here is the example in fiddle.
I wonder if it would be possible to refactor the query below in a smarter way. The current query achieves the desired outcome; however, I am curious if it could be refactored further, perhaps by using a single ROLLUP and eliminating the need for unions. Below is the query.
WITH base_data AS (
    SELECT 
        p,
        id,
        v,
        1 AS Anzahl,
        0 AS Anzahl2,
        'M' AS Period
    FROM t 
    WHERE ts BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') AND SYSDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        p,
        id,
        v,
        0 AS Anzahl,
        1 AS Anzahl2,
        'Y' AS Period
    FROM t 
    WHERE ts BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND SYSDATE
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(p) = 1 THEN 'Gesamt' 
        ELSE COALESCE(p, 'Unbekannt')
    END AS Art_der_Reklamation,
    SUM(Anzahl) AS Anzahl,
    SUM(Anzahl) * 100 / 30 AS AnteilMonat,
    SUM(Anzahl2) AS Anzahl2,
    SUM(Anzahl2) * 100 AS AnteilJahr
FROM base_data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(p)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(id) = 1 THEN 'Gesamt' 
        ELSE COALESCE(TO_CHAR(id), 'Unbekannt')
    END AS Art_der_Reklamation,
    SUM(Anzahl) AS Anzahl,
    SUM(Anzahl) * 100 / 30 AS AnteilMonat,
    SUM(Anzahl2) AS Anzahl2,
    SUM(Anzahl2) * 100 AS AnteilJahr
FROM base_data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(id)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(v) = 1 THEN 'Gesamt' 
        ELSE COALESCE(TO_CHAR(v), 'Unbekannt')
    END AS Art_der_Reklamation,
    SUM(Anzahl) AS Anzahl,
    SUM(Anzahl) * 100 / 30 AS AnteilMonat,
    SUM(Anzahl2) AS Anzahl2,
    SUM(Anzahl2) * 100 AS AnteilJahr
FROM base_data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(v);


Hi - how long does this query take to run currently and how quickly do you need it to run in order for you to consider it optimised? Also, please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query

I don't mean it takes too long, but I wonder if it's possible to refactor the code.

As SQL is a declarative language there is (almost) always a way of refactoring a SQL statement. As what the query optimizer generates and executes is not necessarily the same as the SQL statement you've written then re-factoring a query that doesn't have a performance issue is probably pointless - you could spend time re-writing your query and the query optimizer might generate the same execution plan as for the original query

You can use grouping by grouping sets ( ... ) to generate subtotals for each  column and the overall total:
with rws as ( 
  select 
    t.*, 
    case when ts between trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and sysdate then 1 else 0 end as mm,
    case when ts between trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') and sysdate then 1 else 0 end as yyyy
  from t
  where ts between trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') and sysdate
)
select CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(id) = 0 THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(id), 'Unbekannt') 
        WHEN GROUPING(p) = 0 THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(p), 'Unbekannt')
        WHEN GROUPING(v) = 0 THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(v), 'Unbekannt')
        ELSE 'Gesamt'
    END v,
    SUM(mm) AS Anzahl,
    SUM(mm) * 100 / 30 AS AnteilMonat,
    SUM(yyyy) AS Anzahl2,
    SUM(yyyy) * 100 AS AnteilJahr
from rws
group by grouping sets ( (p), (id), (v), () )


That's great. But like this I have only one total. And no subtotals. Actually I need subtotals for every group only. How can I reach it?

What do you mean? This query gives the same results as those shown in the linked DB fiddle

Not really. With the query from fiddle I have 3 gesamt (one pro group) and with the query above only 1 gesamt.

Maybe I can do group by grouping sets ( rollup(p), rollup(id), rollup(v) ). But then how can I recoginse which Gesamt belongs to which group?

I see now - the Gesamt rows all have the same values. Do you really need all three?

The example is simplified...  In reality not everything is same.

All the Gesamt rows show the grand total... how can they be different? If you must have them you can use rollup in grouping sets as you propose and the group_id() to tell which is which. They're numbered from 0-N for N duplicate groups.

In reality, I compute the percentage based on the function amount. How can I get the number of groups? Specifically, I want to know the number of groups for meldungpers, reklagrund, and verursacher.

I'm not sure which groups you need the number of. It may be better to ask a new question that includes the details of why you need many grand totals.

I just mean the how can I figure out which grouping set is it...

You can't - they all return the same thing (the grand total). Use the group_id() function to differentiate them. Then choose your own method to decide which is which - I would match the order they're listed in grouping sets. If somehow there is a real difference in the data between these grand totals, you're going to have to show us exactly how.

can you share your expected output, and response time for the query.
Further this query can be optimized, you can remove redundant processing in your CTE with the UNION clause rather than a UNION clause you can get: AnzahlMonat and AnzahlJahr on the basis of cases:
WITH base_data AS (
    SELECT 
        p,
        id,
        v,
        CASE WHEN ts BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') AND SYSDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AnzahlMonat,
        CASE WHEN ts BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND SYSDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AnzahlJahr
    FROM t 
    WHERE ts BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND SYSDATE
)

